# Maximum transaction weight

Tags: transaction-size

According to a different StackExchange [question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/how-many-destinations-can-there-be-for-a-single-transaction/11081#11081), the max transaction weight is half the penalty-free block weight, or was in protocol v8.

Looking into it however, I found `check_tx_semantic()` which says:

```
get_transaction_weight(tx) >= m_blockchain_storage.get_current_cumulative_block_weight_limit() - CRYPTONOTE_COINBASE_BLOB_RESERVED_SIZE
```

Now, `get_current_cumulative_block_weight_limit()` gets `m_current_block_cumul_weight_limit` which is the max block size, so it seems there are conflicting ideas.

What is the correct maximum transaction weight in protocol v12?

Note: after bulletproofs in protocol v8, transaction size gets inflated when there are more than two outputs. The new metric is called 'transaction weight'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct maximum transaction size in protocol v12?

Quoting the [source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/fb64463c4c49a92ab1345eab1a2b2c9bcf0b6708/src/cryptonote_core/tx_pool.cpp#L83) of `get_transaction_weight_limit` in `tx_pool.cpp`:

```
  // from v8, limit a tx to 50% of the minimum block weight
  if (version >= 8)
    return get_min_block_weight(version) / 2 - CRYPTONOTE_COINBASE_BLOB_RESERVED_SIZE;
```

Which is used when adding a tx to the pool in `tx_memory_pool::add_tx`, `core::add_new_tx` and various other places eventually call through to it as well.

> Looking into it, however, I found check_tx_semantic() ...

If you look a bit more you find that `core::check_tx_semantic` is only called by `core::handle_incoming_tx_accumulated_batch` which doesn't look to be called by anything.